# How can I get my dropdown to goto a page and display a selected record?

Tags: php

first time poster and very new to mysqli, sorry if my question is not correct.
I have a table (staff) with id, staffname and profile.
I wish to be able to edit/add records by selecting a staff member from a dropdown and after submit, go to a new page called add-edit-staff.php.

I have created the page add-edit-staff.php, and it works perfectly. If I put manually type "add-edit-staff.php" in the address bar of my browser the form comes up to add a new record. If I manually type "add-edit-staff.php?id=1" in the address bar of my browser the form comes up to edit the record with id 1.

Now to my issue, I have a page called view-staff.php. this page has a form with a dropdown displaying the field "staffmember". I want to be able to select a record from that dropdown and go to the corresponding record on my add-edit-staff.php page based on the id of that record. Currently when I select my record, it comes straight back to mt add-edit-staff.php page. it does this because the view-staff.php page is not sending the id of the record in the URL.

I have attached my code and I would appreciate some advice on how to resolve my  issue. As I said, I am very new to this and I have been trying to adapt code to suit my goal but I cant seem to get my head around it.

Thanks in advance..

add-edit-staff.php

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

?>
<?php
// creates the new/edit record form
function renderForm($staffmember = '', $profile ='', $error = '', $id = '')
{
?>
<form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <?php if ($id != '') { ?><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                    <?php $id; ?><?php } ?>

        <table width="675" border="0" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><strong>Staff Member</strong></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top"><input name="staffmember" type="text" name="staffmember" size="147" value="<?php echo $staffmember; ?>"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Staff Profile</strong></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><textarea name="profile" cols="110" rows="10"><?php echo $profile; ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

                  <p></p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
            </form>

</body></html>

<?php }
    /*
       EDIT RECORD

    */
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
        if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
        {
            // get variables from the URL/form
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $staffmember = htmlentities($_POST['staffmember'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $profile = htmlentities($_POST['profile'], ENT_QUOTES);

            // check that staffmember and profile are both not empty
            if ($staffmember == '' || $profile == '')
            {
                // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                renderForm($staffmember, $profile, $error, $id);
            }
            else
            {
                // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE staff SET staffmember = ?, profile = ?
                    WHERE id=?"))
                {
                    $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $staffmember, $profile, $id);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }
                // show an error message if the query has an error
                else
                {
                    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                }

                // redirect the user once the form is updated
                header("Location: view-staff.php");
            }
        }
        // if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
        else
        {
            echo "Error!";
        }
    }
    // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
    else
    {
        // make sure the 'id' value is valid
        if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
        {
            // get 'id' from URL
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            // get the recod from the database
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id=?"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($id, $staffmember, $profile);
                $stmt->fetch();

                // show the form
                renderForm($staffmember, $profile, NULL, $id);

                $stmt->close();
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
            }
        }
        // if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view-staff2.php page
        else
        {
            header("Location: view-staff.php");
        }
    }
}



    /*

       NEW RECORD

    */
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // get the form data
        $staffmember = htmlentities($_POST['staffmember'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $profile = htmlentities($_POST['profile'], ENT_QUOTES);

        // check that staffmember and profile are both not empty
        if ($staffmember == '' || $profile == '')
        {
            // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
            renderForm($staffmember, $profile, $error);
        }
        else
        {
            // insert the new record into the database
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT staff (staffmember, profile) VALUES (?, ?)"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $staffmember, $profile);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
            }

            // redirec the user
            header("Location: view-staff2.php");
        }

    }
    // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
    else
    {
        renderForm();
    }
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

view-staff.php

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add-edit-staff.php">
<select name="staffmember">
  <?php
                    // get the records from the database
                    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY id"))
                    {
                            // display records if there are records to display
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                            {

                                   {
                                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">";
                                            echo $row['staffmember'];
                                            echo "</option>";
}
?>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="   Edit   ">
              </form<?php

    }
    }
                            // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
    else
    {
    echo "No results to display!";
    }
    }
                            // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
    else
    {
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
    }

                    // close database connection
    $mysqli->close();

?>
       <a href="add-edit-staff.php"><h3 align="center">Add New Record</h3></a>


      <?php else : ?>
      <p>
            <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: use if condition with while

Comment: Do you know the difference between the methods `get` and `post`?

Comment: You are submitting your form from view-staff.php to add-edit-staff.php in a POST and not in a GET. Read up on POST and GET on w3schools (they have php examples on how to handle POST).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your view-staff.php with this

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="add-edit-staff.php">
<select name="id">
  <?php
                    // get the records from the database
                    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM staff ORDER BY id"))
                    {
                            // display records if there are records to display
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                            {

                                   {
                                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                            echo "<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">";
                                            echo $row['staffmember'];
                                            echo "</option>";
}
?>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="   Edit   ">
              </form<?php

    }
    }
                            // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
    else
    {
    echo "No results to display!";
    }
    }
                            // show an error if there is an issue with the database query
    else
    {
    echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
    }

                    // close database connection
    $mysqli->close();

?>
       <a href="add-edit-staff.php"><h3 align="center">Add New Record</h3></a>


      <?php else : ?>
      <p>
            <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

AND add-edit-staff.php

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

?>
<?php
// creates the new/edit record form
function renderForm($staffmember = '', $profile ='', $error = '', $id = '')
{
?>
<form action="" method="post">
            <div>
                <?php if ($id != '') { ?><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                    <?php $id; ?><?php } ?>

        <table width="675" border="0" cellspacing="10">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top"><strong>Staff Member</strong></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="top"><input name="staffmember" type="text" name="staffmember" size="147" value="<?php echo $staffmember; ?>"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>Staff Profile</strong></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><textarea name="profile" cols="110" rows="10"><?php echo $profile; ?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        </table>

                  <p></p>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
            </form>

</body></html>

<?php }
    /*
       EDIT RECORD

    */
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
        if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
        {
            // get variables from the URL/form
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $staffmember = htmlentities($_POST['staffmember'], ENT_QUOTES);
            $profile = htmlentities($_POST['profile'], ENT_QUOTES);

            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE staff SET staffmember = ?, profile = ?
                WHERE id=?"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $staffmember, $profile, $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            // show an error message if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
            }

            // redirect the user once the form is updated
            header("Location: view-staff.php");
        }
        // if the 'id' variable is not valid, show an error message
        else
        {
            echo "Error!";
        }
    }
    // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, get the info from the database and show the form
    else
    {
        // make sure the 'id' value is valid
        if (is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
        {
            // get 'id' from URL
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            // get the recod from the database
            if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id=?"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                $stmt->execute();

                $stmt->bind_result($id, $staffmember, $profile);
                $stmt->fetch();

                // show the form
                renderForm($staffmember, $profile, NULL, $id);

                $stmt->close();
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "Error: could not prepare SQL statement";
            }
        }
        // if the 'id' value is not valid, redirect the user back to the view-staff2.php page
        else
        {
            header("Location: view-staff.php");
        }
    }
}



    /*

       NEW RECORD

    */
// if the 'id' variable is not set in the URL, we must be creating a new record
else
{
    // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        // get the form data
        $staffmember = htmlentities($_POST['staffmember'], ENT_QUOTES);
        $profile = htmlentities($_POST['profile'], ENT_QUOTES);

        // check that staffmember and profile are both not empty
        if ($staffmember == '' || $profile == '')
        {
            // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
            renderForm($staffmember, $profile, $error);
        }
        else
        {
            // insert the new record into the database
            if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT staff (staffmember, profile) VALUES (?, ?)"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("ss", $staffmember, $profile);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
            // show an error if the query has an error
            else
            {
                echo "ERROR: Could not prepare SQL statement.";
            }

            // redirec the user
            header("Location: view-staff2.php");
        }

    }
    // if the form hasn't been submitted yet, show the form
    else
    {
        renderForm();
    }
}

// close the mysqli connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, it is now taking me to the correct page and record, but when I update the record on add-edit-staff,php, it says "ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!"

Comment: Your `add-edit-staff.php` here provided is incomplete please show full code

Comment: yes, `staffmember` and `profile` both display correctly on the **add-edit-staff.php** webpage, but when I try to change just the profile record and click submit, I get the error "ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!" 
If I remove the error section from the php, when I update the profile, all data is wiped out from the profile field in the table.

Comment: `staffmember` or `profile` could not be empty, try fill some data and submit it

Comment: both fields already have data, I need to be able to edit either `staffmember`, `profile` or both fields...

Comment: thank you Dhinju, did you edit add-edit-staff.php ? Now I get an error on that page "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\phptrans\admin\add-edit-staff2.php on line 257" line 257 is the last line on the page

Comment: `add-edit-staff2.php` is not here. and i edited `add-edit-staff.php` if this work properly then please accept my answer